# Text in sidenav gets messed up when i close it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a sidenav (not even sure if that is what its called) on my site but when I close it, the text in the sidenav gets messed up. I tried `@media screen and (max-width: 50px)` but that ofcourse doesn't work on a overlay.

If you want to see what i mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/ehyLghy8/
Trust me, it looks worse on my final website.

Is there any way to have the text stand in place and not moving to the left when I close the nav?

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the transform property instead of the width:

I juste add this in your css

```
#myNav{
  width:100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
```

and modify your functions to play with transform:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.transform = "translateX(0)";
} 

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try `white-space: nowrap` with labels**

```
form label {  
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Is this the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a minimum width to your form element this will achieve the appropriate result.

For instance `min-width: 600px;` will achieve the following: https://jsfiddle.net/ehyLghy8/1/

By doing this we're saying that we don't want that element to be smaller than 600px, therefore the text won't wrap

Comment: If you would use a window thats smaller than 600px. Wouldn't that look weird?

Comment: Yeah totally, it was just an example, `white-space` is the better fix. Although using 100vw (instead of 600px) would be responsive and gives a cool effect!